# ArcMap correct Errors in Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, values, replace

I want to **replace** the all the **-9999 values** in my attribute table **with 0**.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this code inside the Python window. I assume that all those columns with `-9999` are of numeric type:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('pure_proj', "*") as cur:
    for feat in cur:
        for i in range(len(feat)):
            if feat[i] == -9999:
                feat[i] = 0
                cur.updateRow(feat)
```

What we are doing here:

1. Create a cursor connection to the underlying feature class using [`da.UpdateCursor`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).
2. As we got all the fields, we need to check every value in each row. This could be done using the `enumerate` or `range`.
3. If `-9999` is found, we set the value for this particular row's column to be `0`. Afterwards we update this particular row using the `updateRow()` method.

Comment: Did it work for you? I've updated the answer to include more details on the workflow to help you get started.

Comment: Yes, it worked out. I appreciate the explanation you did beneath.